# need to split the particular cell in to two JTextField in Swing Java

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer

i am having one Jtable and assign rendered for column.
Now i want to split particular cell into two parts so that i can provide two value in to it.
Splitting can be through Cellrenderer or may be anything else.[image]

Comment: You don't want much.  Take a look at [this](http://www.crionics.com/public/swing_examples/JTableExamples4.html).  But you could almost accomplish the same thing with a single `TableCellRenderer`

Comment: can be possible by using JSeparator (for example) but important question if will be editable (TableCellEditor) or not

Comment: @ZouZou 1) not, isn't required the url, this code is from public forum then is public, 2) no idea why / who down voted without real reasons probably a) short_cut or b) discharge of static electricity :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `JPanel` with [GridLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html) as the cell renderer:

```
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, 
  boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,int row,int col) {
    if (isSplitted(value) {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,2));
        JLabel left = new JLabel(getLeft(value));
        JLabel right = new JLabel(getRight(value));        
        panel.add(left);
        panel.add(right);    
        return panel; 
      } else {
        return super.getTableCellRendererComponent(
           table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, col)
      }
}
```

Here `getLeft`, `getRight` and `isSplitted` are up to you to define for the value you render in that cell.

If makes sense, you can also optimize retaining an instance of this panel with the two labels; it is possible to reuse it on every call upon setting the required content. For the case when  left and rights components are very different in size, BorderLayout may work better.

Similarly, you can provide the cell editor, just  you need `JTextField` or the like as `JLabel` is not editable. Derive from [AbstractCellEditor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractCellEditor.html), overriding `getCellEditorValue` (return the value composed from the panel) and `getTableCellEditorComponent` (return the panel itself after setting the fields to the current value).

**@Stifler** has commented on my answer:

```
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object obj, 
    boolean isSelected,  boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
    Component cell = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(
      table, obj, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 2));
    if ("History".equals(obj)) {
        JTextField left = new JTextField("Left");
        left.setEditable(true);
        JTextField right = new JTextField("Right");
        left.setEditable(true);
        panel.add(left);
        panel.add(right);
        return panel;
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: i m having the following table

Comment: i also put the splitting code into the TableCellRenderer but now when i am going to edit the newly added Left/Right JTextField, its editing previous value.

Comment: public Component getTableCellRendererComponent( JTable table, Object obj, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column )
{
Component cell = super.getTableCellRendererComponent( table, obj, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column );
JPanel panel = new JPanel( new GridLayout( 1, 2 ) );


if( "History".equals( obj ) )
{
JTextField left = new JTextField( "Left" );
left.setEditable( true );
JTextField right = new JTextField( "Right" );
left.setEditable( true );
panel.add( left );
panel.add( right );
return panel;
}

return cell;

}

Comment: @Stifler Edit the question to write your code. It is very confusing to  read code from comment section.